# ValueError: "Columns must be same length as key" > Python

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I'm using Colab to run the code but I get this error and I can't fix it. Could you help me out?
I don't know what to do in order to fix it because I have tried to change upper case or lower case.

```
    #Inativos: ajustar nomes das colunas
    dfInativos = dfInativos.rename(columns={'userId': 'id'})
    dfInativos = dfInativos.rename(columns={'classId': 'ClasseId'})
    dfInativos[['id','ClasseId','lastActivityDate','inactivityDaysCount','sevenDayInactiveStatus']] = dfInativos
    
    
    #dfInativos['id'] = dfInativos['id'].astype(int, errors = 'ignore')
    #dfInativos['ClasseId'] = dfInativos['ClasseId'].astype(int, errors = 'ignore')
    dfInativos['id'] = pd.to_numeric(dfInativos['id'],errors = 'coerce')
    dfInativos['ClasseId'] = pd.to_numeric(dfInativos['ClasseId'],errors = 'coerce')
    
    #dfInativos.dropna(subset = ['lastActivityDate'], inplace=True)
    dfInativos.drop_duplicates(subset = ['id','ClasseId'], inplace=True)
    dfInativos['seven DayInactiveStatus'] = dfInativos['sevenDayInactiveStatus'].replace(0,'')
    #Add Inactive data to main data frame
    df = df.merge(dfInativos, on=['id','ClasseId'], how='left')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-10fe94c48d1f> in <module>()
      2 dfInativos = dfInativos.rename(columns={'userId': 'id'})
      3 dfInativos = dfInativos.rename(columns={'classId': 'ClasseId'})
----> 4 dfInativos[['id','ClasseId','lastActivityDate','inactivityDaysCount','sevenDayInactiveStatus']] = dfInativos
      5 
      6 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexers.py in check_key_length(columns, key, value)
    426     if columns.is_unique:
    427         if len(value.columns) != len(key):
--> 428             raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
    429     else:
    430         # Missing keys in columns are represented as -1

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the line where it breaks?

Comment: Hello there,
I get the report for inactive users and filter them for unique values. Then they the data is added to another sheet.

Comment: No, not broadly; i mean specifically the line where it breaks, the line where you are assigning `dfInativos` to itself.